# How to execute a command with "=" sign in a desktop shortcut?

Tags: firefox, environment-variables, .desktop

I'm trying to modify my Firefox shortcut in Unity so that it started with a specific parameter. From a terminal, I would start like this:

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox
```

I tried modifying the `firefox.desktop` file so that the Exec line looked like

```
Exec=VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox
```

But this doesn't work (the application doesn't start). I thought it could be a problem with two "=" signs, so I tried

```
Exec="VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox"
```

but this doesn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: Exec="VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl && firefox" ?

Comment: @Rinzwind Not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `env` command

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox
```

See the manpage at `man env`

```
ENV(1)                           User Commands                          ENV(1)

NAME
       env - run a program in a modified environment

SYNOPSIS
       env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

Alternatively, create a wrapper script and call that instead.

Comment: "Should be able to" is all well and good, but "/usr/bin/env VAR=val command" on the command line works, whereas "Exec=/usr/bin/env VAR=val command" in .Desktop entry does not (using 20.04).

Comment: @Lexible, did you find any fix for this?