# Change system language for Gramps in .desktop file

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, 15.04, language-support

I would like to start the genealogy program [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/) with a language (English) other than my locale one (Spanish). I successfully tried to run `Gramps` in terminal via

```
 LANG=en_GB gramps
```

I would like, now, to add this command in the .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` to be able to start `Gramps` in the English language, but I cannot get it to run like this

```
EXEC=LANG=en_GB gramps
```

What can I do?

**Edit:**
For those interested: the suggestion by Jacob down below helped me to start gramps in the given language English via the .desktop file. In addition, I have used the following two commands so that `gramps` in terminal starts in English as well:

```
echo 'LANGUAGE=en_GB PATH=/usr/bin/gramps:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
echo 'alias gramps='LANGUAGE=en_GB /usr/bin/gramps'' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Logout and login!

Comment: See also [How to execute a command with “=” sign in a desktop shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496835/how-to-execute-a-command-with-sign-in-a-desktop-shortcut/496839#496839)

Comment: Too bad. I do not know why `Gramps` is so persistent in using only the locale language. Thank you anyway for your efforts, Jacob!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Gramp and tried it here, and this should really work:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "LANGUAGE=en_GB gramps"
```

`LANGUAGE=` takes precedence over `LANG=`

*Note*

Make sure you run the application from the *local* `.desktop` file: After editing the local one, make *sure* you log out / in before running it again.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jacob, for the fast reply. Unfortunately, it does not function. Gramps still starts in Spanish. [https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Howto:Change_the_language_of_reports#Add_GNOME_Menu_Item](Here) is another proposal which does not function any longer(?). Gramps seems to get the information about which language to use early on from the locale file.

Comment: @TilHund Ah, that actually surprises me. Are you sure you logged out /in since you copied the desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications/` if you didn't it might still run from the global one.

Comment: Yes, Jacob, I am logged in. What would you suggest to do now? I tried to write a "batch" file, too, and wrote the path in the .desktop file, i.e. `EXEC=/path/to/file/in/home/gramps.sh`. With code like this: `LANG=en_GB-UTF-8` ENTER `gramps` to no avail.

Comment: @TilHund I will try and install Gramps, see what happens :)

Comment: Yes, it functions now. I never thought that there is a local place for desktop files and that login/out takes them into effect. Wow. However, the command `gramps` in terminal still uses the system-wide language Spanish rather than English. It is actually another question, but do you know by any chance how to fix this? Maybe with alias when `/etc/bin/gramps` is called in terminal?

Comment: Hi @TilHund if this solves your problem, would you be so kind to accept the answer? (on the left, below the up and down arrows). It makes clear the question is not "unanswered". The other thing: run the command: `LANGUAGE=en_GB.utf8 gramps` from terminal.

Comment: **en_GB.utf8** is not a valid LANGUAGE value. LANGUAGE expects a colon separated list of language codes without any ".utf8" or ".UTF-8" extension. The effect in this case is that it falls back to the original string, and even if it's English it's not the British translation. It should be `LANGUAGE=en_GB`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for mentioning, edited it into the answer. It worked though.

Comment: Great! I'm sure it showed English, but probably not the British translation (if there is a British translation for gramps).

Comment: Done my edit too

Answer (score 2):

A more generic way, compared to playing with a .desktop file, ~/.bashrc, etc., is to create the file **~/bin/gramps** and give it this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANGUAGE=en_GB
exec /usr/bin/gramps $@
```

Also run `chmod +x ~/bin/gramps`. Then, next time you log in, English will be the display language however you start gramps.

Comment: Why do we actually have to log out and in again?

Comment: @TilHund After you created the directory `~/bin`, the directory needs to "show up" in  $PATH. You can do that either by running `source ~/.profile` or log out /in. In the case of creating (copying) a local `.desktop` file, Unity needs to switch its "focus" from the global one to the local one.

Answer (score 1):

**My workaround:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PhotoFiltre Studio X
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
**Exec=env LC_ALL="pl_PL.UTF8" /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "PhotoFiltre Studio X" %F**
Icon=/home/gajowy/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/PhotoFiltre Studio X
Name[fr_FR]=PhotoFiltre Studio X
StartupWMClass=pfstudiox.exe
Categories=Graphics;RasterGraphics;
```