# Prefix argument for starting chromium with hardware acceleration

Tags: chromium, .desktop

I wanted to enable the hadware acceleration of the chromium browser and therefore followed [this article](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-enable-hardware-accelerated.html). At first it didn't work, but then I discovered a comment in the comment section which suggested to use the command `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 chromium-browser` to start the chromium browser via terminal with hardware acceleration enabled and it worked! Then I thought to create a new custom desktop file for chromium to include this prefix automatically. I copied the existing dekstop file from `/usr/share/applications` to `/home/myUser/.local/share/applications`. Then I edited the desktop file and infront of every `Exec` Keyword I added `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965`. The resulting `.dekstop` file looks so now:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Chromium Web Browser
Name[ast]=Restolador web Chromium
...
Exec=LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 chromium-browser %U
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=chromium-browser
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Name[ast]=Abrir una Ventana Nueva
Name[bg]=Отваряне на Нов прозорец
...
Exec=LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 chromium-browser

[Desktop Action Incognito]
Name=Open a New Window in incognito mode
...
Exec=LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 chromium-browser --incognito

[Desktop Action TempProfile]
Name=Open a New Window with a temporary profile
Name[ast]=Abrir una ventana nueva con perfil temporal
Name[bg]=Отваряне на Нов прозорец с временен профил
...
Exec=LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 chromium-browser --temp-profile
```

But now chromium browser is not found anymore by the launcher, so it seems like my `.desktop` file is somehow wrong. Can somebody explain to me what the problem could be here?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Try `Exec=/usr/bin/env LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 chromium-browser --incognito` - see [How to execute a command with “=” sign in a desktop shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496835/how-to-execute-a-command-with-sign-in-a-desktop-shortcut/496839#496839)

Comment: thank you very much! That did it! :)