# Making Steam run "GDK_SCALE=3" automatically

Tags: steam, scaling

Ubuntu 20.04, novice user.

I am trying to solve some scaling issues with Steam. I use a 4K TV so I have my display set to 300% which works well however Steam is ignoring this.

I found `GDK_SCALE=3 /usr/bin/steam` online that fixes it, but I want that command to run when I use Steam from my menu.

I tried editing the `steam.sh` in my home folder, but Steam either restores the original `.sh` or it refuses to open.

Comment: I don't use steam, but assuming it is launched via a .desktop file you might try something like this: [How to execute a command with “=” sign in a desktop shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496835/how-to-execute-a-command-with-sign-in-a-desktop-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

Add `export GTK_SCALE=3` to `/usr/games/steam`