# How to edit the qsettings in a .desktop file so it does not dissappear from the applications nor favorites list

Tags: .desktop

I need to change the qsettings in a wolfram*.desktop file and I have tried with the copy in /usr/share/applications and a local copy in ./local/share/applications. Whenever I edit the .desktop files it dissappears from the applications menu and from the dock as well.

This is how my file .dekstop file looks [Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 Type=Application Name=Mathematica 12 Comment=Technical Computing System TryExec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/Executables/Mathematica Exec=QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2 /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathe> Icon=wolfram-mathematica MimeType=application/mathematica;application/x-mathematica;application/vnd.wolf>

Comment: If the local copy makes the application disappear from the menu, probably because of an error in the content. Posting the edited version would help. Not sure what "qsettings" refers to though?

Comment: This is how my file .dekstop file looks 


[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Mathematica 12
Comment=Technical Computing System
TryExec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/Executables/Mathematica
Exec=QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2 /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathe>
Icon=wolfram-mathematica
MimeType=application/mathematica;application/x-mathematica;application/vnd.wolf>

Comment: @RuthLazkoz please use the [edit] button to add that information to your question

Comment: You might find this helpful: [How to execute a command with “=” sign in a desktop shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496835/how-to-execute-a-command-with-sign-in-a-desktop-shortcut)

Comment: This is my new working version produced with the previous helpful comments [Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Mathematica 12
Comment=Technical Computing System
TryExec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/Executables/Mathematica
Exec=/usr/bin/env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1  /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica>
Icon=wolfram-mathematica
MimeType=application/mathematica;application/x-mathematica;application/vnd.wolf>