# autostart emulationstation using custom variable

Tags: command-line, autostart

I'm setting up [retropie](https://retropie.org.uk/) with `emulationstation` on my Nvidia Jetson Nano. These dev boards are only supported for 18.04. Unfortunately there's a [bug with SDL2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsdl2/+bug/1775067) so `emulationstation` crashes on startup unless I start it with `DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0 emulationstation` from the command line. Now that I have a workaround I need to incorporate it into `~/.config/autostart/retropie.desktop`

The original is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar -e emulationstation
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[de_DE]=RetroPie
Name=rpie
Comment[de_DE]=RetroPie
Comment=retropie
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/retropie.svg
Categories=Game
```

I tried

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar -e "bash -c DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0 emulationstation"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[de_DE]=RetroPie
Name=rpie
Comment[de_DE]=RetroPie
Comment=retropie
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/retropie.svg
Categories=Game
```

With no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd try the `env` command ex. `gnome-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar -- env DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0 emulationstation` (note the use of `--` in place of `-e`, which iirc was deprecated even in 18.04). See also [How to execute a command with "=" sign in a desktop shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496835/how-to-execute-a-command-with-sign-in-a-desktop-shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing the startup command in a script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS=0
/usr/bin/emulationstation
```

saved to /home/pgcudahy/startemulationstation.sh and ran `chmod +x /home/pgcudahy/startemulationstation.sh` to make it executable

And then modified ~/.config/autostart/retropie.desktop to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar -e /home/pgcudahy/startemulationstation.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[de_DE]=RetroPie
Name=rpie
Comment[de_DE]=RetroPie
Comment=retropie
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/retropie.svg
Categories=Game
```